# How do I create an Array or ArrayList with a looped, column of strings that contain integers?

Tags: java, arrays, string, loops, arraylist

I have tried so hard to find a solution to this problem! Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Weather {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //Getting the file.
        String fileName = "weather2013.txt";

        //Lines!
        String line;

        //Creating arrayList object
        ArrayList aList = new ArrayList();
        try {
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                aList.add(line);
            }
            //Close the file
            input.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("File not found!");
        }

        //Station ID Number:
        String firstLine = aList.get(1).toString();
        String stationIDStr = firstLine.substring(0, 6);
        int StationID = Integer.parseInt(stationIDStr);
        //System.out.println(StationID);

        //WBAN ID Number:
        String wbanIDstr = firstLine.substring(7, 12);
        int wbanID = Integer.parseInt(wbanIDstr);
        //System.out.println(wbanID);

        //Year!
        String yearStr = firstLine.substring(12, 18).trim();
        int year = Integer.parseInt(yearStr);
        //System.out.println(year);

        //Remove line of text (not needed)
        aList.remove(0);

        //Fog days:
        int fogDays = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < aList.size(); i++) {
            String listString = aList.get(i).toString(); //iterate each readLINE -> String
            String lastDigits = listString.substring(132, 137); //Each entry from 132-137 only
            char fogIndicator = lastDigits.charAt(0);
            if (fogIndicator == '1') {
                fogDays++;
            }
        }
        //System.out.println(fogDays);


        //Maximum and minimum average temps
        for (int i = 0; i < aList.size(); i++) {
            String listString = aList.get(i).toString();
            String averageTempDigits = listString.substring(24, 30).trim();
        }
    }
}
```

The specific part of the code where I am having trouble is the VERY last for loop.
Here's what's being outputted:

```
    47.9
    41.8
    .
    .
    .
    .
    41.8
    67.0
    66.5
```

I would like to know how to get this column above into an Array or ArrayList?

Comment: Put all this code aside for a moment and write a new small program where you hard code a few strings that are numbers and learn how to put them into an Array or ArrayList. You should be able to google creating an Array or ArrayList and do this for yourself.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are asking. You clearly know how to add items to a list (as you are already doing this). You also know how to get a 'column' from your input (as you are doing this too). So can't you just add the column values you are extracting to a list?

Comment: I finally figured it out, but basically I was having trouble reading one single string of numbers as opposed to just keeping the individual little strings which is what my output was. My solution to this was to use StringBuilder within the same loop appending averageTempDigits. I just got a little confused and overwhelmed, but it was an easy fix.